# How to replace vowels in this code?

Tags: python

I'm creating a "guess the word" game for my intro to programming class. It uses parallel tuples where one list is the random words & the second list is the corresponding hints for those words. The game is supposed to print one of the random words with underscores in place of the vowels (ex: J_p_n instead of Japan) and the user guesses the word based off of that & the hint. With my current code, it doesn't print the word without the vowels but instead just prints a single letter. How do I fix this?

```
import random

#Parallel tuples
guesswords = ("Japan","France","Mexico","Italy")
guesshints = ("Sushi comes from here","Croissants come from here","Tacos come from here","Pizza comes from here") 

#Variables
new_words = ""
vowels = "AaEeIiOoUu"

#Random
index = random.randrange(len(guesswords))
guesses = 5


#Replacing vowels
for letter in guesswords:
    if letter not in vowels:
        new_words += letter
    else:
        new_words += "_"

#Output        
print(new_words[index].center(80, " "))
print("Hint:",guesshints[index])
while guesses > 0:
    input_string = "\nGuess the word! You have " + str(guesses) + " guesses remaining: "
    user_guess = input(input_string)
    if user_guess.upper() == guesswords[index].upper():
        print("YOU WIN")
        break
    guesses -= 1

print("GAME OVER")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `for letter in guesswords:` to `for letter in guesswords[index]:`.  And remove `[index]` from this line `print(new_words[index].center(80, " "))`

Comment: This solved my issue! Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Lauren Glad to help.  If you feel this answer is the best, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex is probably the easiest solution:

```
import re
original_word = 'America'
vowels = re.compile(r'[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
with_underscores = re.sub(vowels, '_', original_word)
print with_underscores
```

Result:

```
_m_r_c_
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reconstructing the word, you could just try something like this

```
for v in vowels:
    word = word.replace(v,'_')
```